# drawing just half of a matrix in matplotlib with python

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

How can I draw only half of a matrix, e.g. the upper / lower part of a matrix, with pcolor for example?

Suppose I have a n x n matrix and I draw it using pcolor(my_matrix).  I want only the lower half to be shown since other values are redundant.  How can this be done?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Is it OK to plot zeros in the other half?

```
pcolor(mat*tri(*shape(mat)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `set_ylim`:

```
X = scipy.rand(10,10)
f = pylab.figure()
ax = f.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax.pcolor(X)
ax.set_ylim([0,5])
f.show()
```